# multiple controllers for one view php mvc design

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am very new to MVC.

I just finished reading a book and am trying to implement what I have learned, but I am stuck. In the book and some other explanations I have read online, it's always one controller for one view, like navigation view being controlled by its controller, login form controlled by its own controller.

But I have a header with couple of navigation links, and a search form.  Do I separate navigation from searching or assume searching is part of navigation and just control them all in one controller?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you seem to have the impression that "template" and "view" is the same thing. It's wrong. A properly done view will juggle multiple templates and choose which combination to use based on the current state of the model layer.

As for your navigation & search thing ... well ... it's confusing. Each link in navigation would point to either a different controller entirely or a different methods of controller. And search query would definitely be submitted to a separate controller/view pair.

The navigation+search is just a template, that is used in multiple views as part of the complete response.